# gstreamer 1.0 sdk application to capture RTP Video Issue

Tags: sdk, gstreamer

I have ran this code many times trying to figure out why it doesn't work. I am getting the feed from a IP camera. The program goes through each but then it fails to play. The original start out was
 **gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc address=[ip] port=[port] ! application/x-rtp,clock-rate=10,media=video ! rtpmp4vdepay ! decodebin ! d3dvideosink**
I used gst_parse_launch() with it and works but for some reason won't play. I have been trying figure out what I am doing wrong.
convertString.h just throws the Char *port to a method to convert string to int.I don't want to use the gst_parse_launch() because I am wanting to use it to overlay into application.
Anybody have any idea what I am missing?

```
#include <gst/gst.h>
#include <gst/video/videooverlay.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "convertString.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <direct.h>

void nullvalues(GstElement*,GstBus*,GstMessage*);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{

GstElement *pipeline,*sink,*source, *rtppay,*filter1,*decodebin;
GstCaps *filtercaps;
GstBus *bus;
GstMessage *msg;
gboolean link_ok = FALSE;
GstStateChangeReturn ret;
char *ip_address = [ip];
char *port = [port];
char *window_handle = "";
char *title = "";
int wid;
char *sourcestring = "";
#define url_size 28
char url[url_size];
strcpy_s(url,url_size,"");


while ((argc > 1) && (argv[1][0] == '-'))
{
     switch (argv[1][1])
     {
        case 'i':
            ip_address = &argv[1][2];
            break;

        case 'p':
            port = &argv[1][2];
            break;
        case 'w':
            window_handle = &argv[1][2];
            break;
        case 't':
            title = &argv[1][2];
            break;
    }

    ++argv;
    --argc;
}

strcat_s(url,url_size,"udp://");
strcat_s(url,url_size,ip_address);
strcat_s(url,url_size,":");
strcat_s(url,url_size,port);

/* Initialize GStreamer */
gst_init(&argc,&argv);


/* Build Pipeline */

if(title != "")
pipeline = gst_pipeline_new (title);
else
    pipeline = gst_pipeline_new("My pipeline");

source = gst_element_factory_make ("udpsrc","source");

filter1 = gst_element_factory_make("capsfilter","filter");

rtppay = gst_element_factory_make( "rtpmp4vdepay", "depayl");

decodebin = gst_element_factory_make ("decodebin","decode");

sink = gst_element_factory_make ("d3dvideosink", "sink");

gst_bin_add_many (GST_BIN (pipeline),source,filter1,rtppay,decodebin,sink, NULL);

filtercaps = gst_caps_new_simple("application/x-rtp","clock-rate",G_TYPE_INT,10,"media",G_TYPE_STRING,"video",NULL);

g_object_set(GST_OBJECT(source),"address",ip_address,NULL);
g_object_set(GST_OBJECT(source),"port",StringToInt(port),NULL);

g_object_set (G_OBJECT (filter1), "caps",filtercaps,NULL);
gst_caps_unref(filtercaps);

link_ok = gst_element_link_many(source,filter1,rtppay,decodebin,sink);
if(!link_ok)
  printf("%s\nNOPE\n");

/* Start playing */
ret = gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_READY);
if(ret == GST_STATE_CHANGE_FAILURE)
printf("\nFailed\n");
else if(ret == GST_STATE_CHANGE_SUCCESS)
printf("\nSuccess\n");

/* Wait until error or EOS */
bus = gst_element_get_bus (pipeline);
msg = gst_bus_timed_pop_filtered(bus,GST_CLOCK_TIME_NONE,GST_MESSAGE_ERROR | GST_MESSAGE_EOS);

/* Free resources */
if (msg != NULL)
gst_message_unref (msg);
gst_object_unref (bus);
gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);
gst_object_unref (pipeline);
printf("\nDone\n");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the error you get? Use GST_DEBUG.

Comment: I did seperate the element_link_many because it fails. I figured out that linking the decodebin to sink doesn't work. I am new to developing these application. How would I use that in the application?

Comment: Here is a picture of the debug I used. in the following link http://www.planetkorey.com/tmp/Capture.JPG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using this will solve the problem
[Gstreamer Decodebin](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/manual/html/section-components-decodebin.html)

Answer (score 0):

If gst_parse_launch() is working for you I suggest to use it. You can still overlay the d3dvideosink in your application.

Just use a unique name for the d3dvideosink element in the pipeline definition (e.g. "d3dvideosink name=myvideosink").

Get a handle to the d3dvideosink from the pipeline via gst_bin_get_by_name(). This handle should then also support the GstVideoOverlay interface and you can set the overlay via gst_video_overlay_set_window_handle().